# Setup for rsyslog to log from two network devices

Tags: syslog

I have 2 VOIP devices on my network (ht502 and ht704) which are both capable of sending their log info as syslog data. Receiver is a little Raspberry on Raspbian.

I wanted to configure syslog to receive messages from both VOIP devices and store them into their respective (different) log files. So far I failed to accomplish that.

I enabled syslog (by uncommenting the below lines in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`):

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
```

I created two files in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` as follows.

```
ht704.conf
$template NetworkLog, "/var/log/ht704.log"
:fromhost-ip, isequal, "192.168.11.160" -?NetworkLog

ht502.conf
$template NetworkLog, "/var/log/ht502.log"
:fromhost-ip, isequal, "192.168.11.162" -?NetworkLog
```

Note the respective different IP addresses.

And restarted the serice:

```
service rsyslog restart
```

It turns out however that all output lands in the `/var/log/ht502.log` file.

Example:

```
Nov  7 19:05:39 HT-502 [00: 0B:82:42:31:62]: [1.0.14.1] NAT::checkNAT: detected NAT environment for account 1
Nov  7 19:05:39 HT-502 [00: 0B:82:42:31:62]: [1.0.14.1] NAT::addPortMapping(STUN), iport = 49260
Nov  7 19:05:39 HT704 [00: 0B:82:65:DD:1C] [1.0.5.10]:System uptime: 1846
Nov  7 19:05:39 HT704 [00: 0B:82:65:DD:1C] [1.0.5.10]:System memory: 13213696/724992/0/794624
Nov  7 19:05:40 HT-502 [00: 0B:82:42:31:62]: [1.0.14.1] SIPClientTransaction::sendRequest: Request 15 is sent
Nov  7 19:05:40 HT-502 [00: 0B:82:42:31:62]: [1.0.14.1] SIPStack(0)::run: Active transactions: 2
```

On top of all I actually just noticed that the messages from the VOIP devices also unexpectedly showed up in `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog`. I don't think they should show up there. Or should they?

Any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR :

Your templates are clobbering each other(although they do not seem to be inherited by other `.conf` files, they are conflicting - your guess is as good as mine).

**Rename** `NetworkLog` to a unique name per file.

**Add** `& ~` as the last line in `ht704.conf` and `ht502.conf`

Alternative(cleaner):

create a single `.conf` file in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` containing the following:

`:fromhost-ip, isequal, "192.168.11.160" /var/log/ht704.log
& ~
:fromhost-ip, isequal, "192.168.11.162" /var/log/ht502.log
& ~`

with formatters example:

`$template RFC3164fmt,"<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg%"
:fromhost-ip, isequal, "192.168.11.160" /var/log/ht704.log;RFC3164fmt
:fromhost-ip, isequal, "192.168.11.162" /var/log/ht502.log;RFC3164fmt
& ~`

Long Version :

I recently found myself struggling to understand the precedence and syntax of these files and and found this question while googling. I would like to link to the documentation but I found it terribly hard to parse and it seems there is already an incentive to improve it underway here:  https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog-doc
As a result, most of the advice comes from **empirical evidence**(things I tried).

[image - help for rsyslog docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bnwa.png)

TIL:

The `FILENAME`s in `/etc/rsyslog.d` are operated on with alphabetical precedence[collation dependent](i.e. why the default is named `50-default.conf`).  As an example I was trying to have multiple output files with different formatting based on the same rule/condition ( `:fromhost-ip,` etc. ); the answer was to have the **first** file read(alphabetically/collationally) do whatever and **exclude** the  `STOP` (`& ~`) while presenting a different output to the **second** file(alphabetically/collationally) **AND** **including the `STOP` (`& ~`) .
The first file in this example was named `10-ddwrt.conf` and the second was named `15-ddwrt.conf`.

Hope this helps and please feel free to improve upon it.  I specifically did not get into the "new" syntax as it is incompatible with older version of `rsyslog`.

Comment: Modified into single config file works OK. Needed `\n` at the end of `$template` line to print newline into logs.